# Windows Installer : SpawnAndWaitDialog not getting closed automatically?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, advanced-installer

I am using a C# custom action followed by a SpawnAndWait Dialog. 
Something Like
PROPERTY WORK_DONE="False"
1.LaunchCustomAction (This does some work and sets WORK_DONE to True)
2.Show SpawnAndWait (Exit when WORK_DONE="True")

Problem,For SpawnAndWait Dialog to Appear,  I need to mark my CustomAction as
  asynchronous, that is to continue installation without waiting for the custom action to finish. But Whenever I do this, Properties are not getting updated and as a result SpawnAndWait Dialog doesn't get closed automatically.

If I don't mark my Condition as async, The dialog doesn't appear and it waits for the custom action to finish first.

My Requirement is to Show a small popup window that lets the user know that there is a background task going on, Please wait.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

I am using C# custom Action via Wix Toolset to build the custom action and AdvancedInstaller to build the installer.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you (if you are willing to) to write your custom action as an unmanaged custom action written in native C++ and use the [MsiSetProperty function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to set your property. There are lots of Windows Installer incompatibilities and limitations in what regards its integration with managed custom actions.

If you still need to use a managed C# custom action please try to add your custom action as a custom action with sequence in Advanced Installer if this configuration is suitable for your scenario.